# How to divide one column multi row into different column in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to divide following column into two different column

Table x

```
ID
1
2
.
.
10
```

--Output Should be like this

```
A   B
-- --
1   6
2   7
3   8
4   9
5   10
```

I tried this, but won't work

```sql
SELECT (SELECT * FROM x WHERE id BETWEEN 1 AND 5),
       (SELECT * FROM x WHERE id BETWEEN 6 AND 10)
    FROM dual;
```

Also used SUBSTR, that also won't work.

Comment: You've not explained the logic of what you are trying to achieve here. In your example sometimes the value in column B is the value in column A + 5, but not always. Does that mean '9' was missing? Something else? How specifically do you want to match a value from set B to set A? What if a value were missing from set A?

Comment: I just now edit my question, can you understand now.

Comment: No - I still don't know why "1" should appear in the same row as "6". I still don't know how you want to deal with non-consecutive values (or duplicate values).

Answer (score 1):

As you did not mention what exactly you want to achieve then i would have write simple query :

```
select case when id <= 5 then id end as col1,
       case when id > 5 and id <= 10 then id end as col2
from table_name
```

Comment: Result vary from expected, output comes like OUTER JOIN.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it using following considering that you have total ids in multiple of 2:

```
With cte as
(Select id, max(id) over() / 2 as mx from your_table) 
Select t1.id as a, t2.id as b
From cte t1 join cte t2
On mod(t1.id, mx) = mod(t2.id, mx) 
And t1.id <= mx and t2.id > mx
Order by t1.id
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

I think you could also use the LEAD function to accomplish your task.  Here is an example:

```sql
WITH x (val) AS
(
  SELECT ROWNUM
  FROM dual
  CONNECT BY ROWNUM < 12
)
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT val AS A, 
             LEAD(val, (SELECT CEIL(COUNT(*)/2) FROM x)) OVER (ORDER BY val) AS B
      FROM x
      ORDER BY val)
WHERE ROWNUM <= (SELECT CEIL(COUNT(*)/2) FROM x);
```

You would just need to replace the WITH clause and its reference in the query with your actual table.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `row_number()` and aggregation

```
select max(case when id <= 5 then id end) as col1,
       max(case when id > 5 then id end) as col2
from (select x.*,
             row_number() over (partition by case when id <= 5 then 1 else 2 end order by id) as seqnum
      from x
     ) x
group by seqnum;
```

Comment: @NaveenM . . . I had accidentally deleted the `from` clause when I posted the query.